# third-party libraries: The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, node-modules

after adding react-native-vision-camera and 2 other packages, I got this error

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':react-native-gesture-handler' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20
```

I know that I need to add `kotlin_version = '1.6.20'` but I have to do it only at the android folder of the `react-native-vision-camera` package. It solves the probleme but everytime I run `./gradlew clean` I have to reset it !

how can I set the `kotlin_version = '1.6.20'` globally for 'all' node_module's packages ?

Comment: There appears to be an [open issue on the GitHub repository on this very matter](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2223).